# Ubuntu 13.10 not booting when installed on a partion on my external USB 1TB drive plugged to a Windows 8.1 laptop

Tags: boot, 13.10

I have Ubuntu 13.10 installed on my HP laptop (windows 8.1) running on an external USB Seagate 1TB hard drive.

I have installed Ubuntu on my external USB drive using the ISO file downloaded from Ubuntu's website and when I reboot my laptop I got the option screen of either running Windows 8.1 off my HP laptop or Ubuntu 13.10 from the USB drive.

Ubuntu doesn't boot properly when I picked the Ubuntu option from the dual boot menu?

Any ideas?

Comment: what was shown on the screen while you try to boot ubuntu?

Comment: I don't understand the title. How is the 1TB USB dirve "in a partition"?

Comment: @JulianStirling there, fixed it =).

Answer (score 0):

Try `Unetbootin` to create bootable usb drives.

1. download unetbootin for windows from [here](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/unetbootin-windows-latest.exe).
2. execute .exe file.after installation,you will see a window like below.
   [image: unetbootin window]
3. now select the iso file from `Diskimage` option
4. select appropriate Usb drive and click ok.
5. the later steps are automatic.
6. once finished,restart your pc and now boot the usb drive.

> Note:-
>   only **fat32** partition on usb drive is supported.
>   if you have multiple fat32 partitions,**ensure to select appropriate partition** by remembering its drive letter.